# Why does this error occur when I try to run a Junit test-case on the Android emulator?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After following some instructions on [Diego Torres blog](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2008/11/android-testing-on-android-platform.html) I am able to test my classes using the regular Eclipse JUnit test-runner, however I also want to be able to run my unit tests from within the emulated android environment.

For now this should make no real difference since the classes I am working on do very basic numerical or networking tasks, but obviously anything which involves the UI or Android API specific functions can only ever be tested on the emulator.

I set up a new run configuration of type AndroidJUnitTest wich uses the android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner, however whenever I fire up the test I get the following error in the console:

```
[2010-01-09 00:45:23 - Pal1]Uploading Pal1.apk onto device 'emulator-5556'
[2010-01-09 00:45:23 - Pal1]Installing Pal1.apk...
[2010-01-09 00:45:25 - Pal1]Success!
[2010-01-09 00:45:25 - Pal1]Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on device emulator-5556
[2010-01-09 00:45:27 - Pal1]Test run failed: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo{org.stodge.traderpal/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43598c28
```

As you might expect, the test ends (without actually having run any tests after the final "Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo" message.

For now my test-cases consist of nothing more than Junit3 and Junit4 boiler-plater code. The  implementations of the tests consist of nothing more than fail() calls. All I need to do at this stage is show that I can execute a basic unit-test in both environments so that I can begin test-driven development.

Notes:
 - Running Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu 64bit
 - Emulator is set to API level 2
 - I'm new to both Android and Java, so excuse my basic questions

Comment: I might be mistaken but I think mixing JUnit 3 and JUnit 4 is generally considered a bad idea. Pick one and stick with it. (I know about Java but not about Android so I may be completely mistaken.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Junit4 test-runner can handle Junit3 test-cases. Sure it's not reccomended, however for now I was trying to see if the incompatibility was specific to one version: It wasn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would ignore what that blog says; it seems pretty outdated.

You don't need to import JUnit libraries or anything like that; the appropriate classes, `TestCase` and so on are integrated into the Android SDK.

Just create a new class in your project and extend `AndroidTestCase`.  Then you can right click the test case (or package of test cases) you want to run and choose Run As → Android JUnit Test.

Also, I would use an API level higher than 2.  [Virtually no devices in use](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) are running Android 1.1; you can safely switch to API level 3, which is Android 1.5 and is a big improvement over previous versions.

Comment: Do you know if the android test-runner can run classes derived from junit.framework.TestCase?

Comment: Yes, that works too. Just "run as" Android JUnit Test as above.

Comment: And do you know if the android test-runner can handle Junit4 style test-cases or is it strictly Junit3 compatible?

Comment: I think Android embeds JUnit4.. I've used annotations on tests, which I think is a JUnit4 feature? Best way to find out is to try! :)